# Wait until process exit that run by Runtime.exec("wmic process call create notepad.exe")

Tags: java, windows, bash

I am working on an application which is able to run programs, monitoring them to reopen in case the user closes them accidentally and close programs on log out.

I am able to get process id of program by parsing the input stream of `wmic process call create <program>`.

I use this code snippet to run programs and detect when program is closed by user. My problem is the command i use(`wmic`) to run programs exit immediately after running them.

How can i achieve detection of program exit?

My code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Process process = null;
        try {
            process = Runtime.getRuntime()
                    .exec("wmic process call create \"notepad.exe\"");
            BufferedReader stdin = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
            String processIdLine = "";
            String line;
            while ((line = stdin.readLine()) != null) {
                if (line.contains("ProcessId")) {
                    processIdLine = line;
                    break;
                }
                System.out.println(line);
            }
            stdin.close();
            String[] param = processIdLine.split("=");
            if (param.length > 1) {
                String pId = param[1];
                pId = pId.replaceAll(";", " ");
                pId = pId.replaceAll(" ", "");
                System.out.println("ID : " + pId);
            }
            try {
                process.waitFor();
              // I want it to hang here till notepad closed.
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println("PROCESSE EXIT");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

NOTE: i dont want to use tasklist command and compare whether process has exited

Comment: If the problem is that `wmic` exicts immediately, why not avoid `wmic` and run `notepad.exe` directly?

Comment: @Thomas notepad was just an example. i want to get process id of programs i run so i can close them on demand by user.

Comment: `Runtime#exec()` returns a `Process` object, which has a `destroy()` method. No need to mess around with low-level things like pids.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at **ZeroTurnaround**'s **[ZT-exec](https://github.com/zeroturnaround/zt-exec)** library which does a lot out of the box for you:

```
try {
  new ProcessExecutor().command("java", "-version").exitValues(3).execute();
} catch (InvalidExitValueException e) {
  System.out.println("Process exited with " + e.getExitValue());
}
```